# Console.Write Error

Tags: c#

I'm Kind of a beginner so i first apologize for what may seem to be a noobish question.
Im trying to test a function by writing the result to the console, but i keep running into errors

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameRPS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        static int Equation(int Damage, int Temp)
        {
            if(Temp > 0)
            {
                int a, b, c;
                a = Damage / 2;
                b = a + Temp;
                c = b - 50;
                return c;

            }
            else
            {
                int d, e, f;
                d = Damage / 2;
                e = d - Temp;
                f = e - 50;
                return f;
            }

            int g;
            g = Equation(75, 25);
            console.WriteLine(g);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me an error saying that "unreachable code" was detected, any ideas on this?
Thanks.

Comment: Your last three lines should be part of `Main` method.

Comment: move these lines to Main:     int g;    g = Equation(75, 25);    console.WriteLine(g);

Comment: Main is the function that runs first in this Console application. It will get called first when the program is started (or you go into debugging)

Answer (score 2):

Your last three lines should be part of Main method

So your code should be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int g;
        g = Equation(75, 25);
        Console.WriteLine(g);
    }

    static int Equation(int Damage, int Temp)
    {
        if (Temp > 0)
        {
            int a, b, c;
            a = Damage / 2;
            b = a + Temp;
            c = b - 50;
            return c;

        }
        else
        {
            int d, e, f;
            d = Damage / 2;
            e = d - Temp;
            f = e - 50;
            return f;
        }

    }
}
```

You are getting the unreachable code error because you are returning from your method `Equation` in `if` and `else` part. The control would never reach those three lines. *(also `console` should be `Console`)*